# Terminar o programa quando inserir um espaço em branco (' ') e não ordena

Tags: python, string, conversão-de-tipo, int, espaço-em-branco

Oi, gente. Então, estou tentando resolver uma questão de Python sobre listas.
**Questão -->** Crie um programa que leia números inteiros do usuário até que uma linha em branco seja inserida. Uma vez que todos os números inteiros foram lidos,

seu programa deve exibir todos os números, seguidos por todos os zeros, seguidos por todos os números positivos.

Dentro de cada grupo, os números devem ser exibidos na mesma ordem em que foram inseridos pelo usuário. Por exemplo, se o usuário digitar os valores 3, -4, 1, 0, -1, 0 e -2, Então seu programa deve gerar os valores -4, -1, -2, 0, 0, 3 e 1.

Seu programa deve exibir cada valor em sua própria linha.

**Tentei isso:**

```
while True:
  valor = int(input('Digite um valor (Linha em branco para parar): '))
  lista.append(valor)
  if valor == " ": 
    print(sorted(lista))
    break
```

Ele está dando esse erro:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Já tentei tirar o int do input, mas quando aperto Enter, ele acaba não encerrando o loop.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá.

Uma opção para resolver a mensagem de erro:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

É modificar o código conforme abaixo:

```
while True:
  valor = input('Digite um valor (Linha em branco para parar): ')
  if valor == '':
    print(sorted(lista))
    break
  else:
    lista.append(int(valor))
```

Fiz o teste com os valores `3, -4, 1, 0, -1, 0, -2` e o resultado foi `-4, -2, -1, 0, 0, 1, 3`.

Espero que isso lhe ajude.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).